# How to re-install the Wi-Fi driver on my Lenovo Laptop after uninstalling it in an attempt to fix connectivity issues?

Tags: windows, laptop, lenovo-laptop

Right out of the package the laptop struggled to connect to my home network, but it worked fine on my phone hotspot. I reset the network setting multiple times but it did nothing.

I saw that uninstalling the Wi-Fi driver and resetting helps so I tried that.

It didn't reinstall and now I can't connect to anything.

What can I do now to re-install the Wi-Fi driver?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact make and model of your Lenovo laptop and your home network’s router?

Comment: Plug it into Ethernet and see if Windows automatically finds the driver. If not, you'll need to download the driver **from Lenovo** from another PC.

Comment: If you have no wired network option, you probably need to go someplace where you can get one, or reset your laptop.

Comment: Alternatively you can use USB tethering from your p`hone as temporary internet connection to perform the suggestions above.

Comment: And if you need further help then make sure to [edit] the question and provide useful information about your hardware and OS. There are thousand of Lenovo laptop models/configurations. We'd like to have info regarding your specific model and, of course, the specific WiFi chip it comes with. The laptop model isn't enough because many may be sold with 1, 2, 4 or even 6 different WiFi devices.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it connected to your Hotspot, but not your Home network, the problem may be in your home network in the first place.

But anyways, you have to get your network adapter fixed. So the information given by You is not that specific, so this is what I could give you as answers,

Firstly, you should go to the device manager, by right clicking the windows start menu icon. Then you may scroll down and find a unidentified or unknown devices group (since the driver is not instaled it should appear here).
And now you may want to select the network adapter from there and then right-click it to select update driver. Now all you have to do is, to wait till Windows automatically searches for a compatible driver and installs it.

Later you can check online databases for  more updated version of the drivers, and update it.

This May not solve the problem if its a problem in your home network, but will ,if its with the drivers.

hope this helps!